# Date.getTime() v.s. Date.now()

Tags: javascript

I noticed that now() can only be called by the Date object. getTime() can only be called by an instance of date.

```
var dd1 = new Date();

//console.log(dd1.now()); //Throws error -> TypeError: Object Mon Aug 19 2013 16:28:03 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) has no method 'now'
console.log(dd1.getTime());

console.log(Date.now());
//console.log(Date.getTime()); //Throws error ->TypeError: Object function Date() { [native code] } has no method 'getTime'
```

Is there a formal name for this difference? Is this the difference between "static" and "non-static." When I create a new instance of Date, shouldn't all methods be inherited?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the difference between properties of the constructor object and properties of the constructor object's prototype. The "now" property is a property of the Date constructor itself, and not a property of `Date.prototype`. It's the opposite situation for "getTime".

Semantically it makes sense: the concept of "now" is independent of any particular date instance.  The "getTime" method is intended to report on the timestamp for the date actually represented by a particular date instance.

If you're defining your own constructors, you can create "class methods" (I personally would hesitate to call them that, but whatever) like this:

```
function MyConstructor() {
  // ...
}

MyConstructor.someMethod = function() {
  // ...
}
```

Then `MyConstructor.someMethod()` calls that function independently of any particular instance of your class.

Comment: Maybe rhis link is helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach no, not really. I think it's a general javascript question which happens to involve `Date`. You could answer the question without ever mentioning `Date`.

Comment: If it is that the question is in regards to Date, do note that `now` is not supported in ie8.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2Fnow

Comment: Okay, I see. and the getTime() method is: MyConstructor.prototype.getTime = function(){}; I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this answers your question but I think these two methods do different things.

`Date.now()` gets "The number of milliseconds between midnight, January 1, 1970, and the current date and time."

Whereas, `dateObj.getTime()` "Returns the number of milliseconds between midnight, January 1, 1970 and the time value in the Date object."

`dateObj.getTime()` requires you to use an object reference, because it uses that to get the difference "between midnight, January 1, 1970 and the time value in the Date object."

You don't need to reference an object with the `Date.now()` method because it doesn't use any object, it simply gets the "number of milliseconds between midnight, January 1, 1970, and the current date and time."

Ref. [Date.Now()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679974%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Ref. [dateObj.getTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7hcawkw2%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I quite forgot date objects don't return an up-to-date time.

Answer (score 5):

"Static" vs "non-static" is one way to put it; also "object methods" vs. "class methods".  You call `now()` on the `Date` **class**, not an object.

`now()` is a factory method of the `Date` class, creating and returning an object - in this case, a `Date` representing the moment when `now()` was called.

`getTime()` requires an existing `Date` object - it's giving you a property (in this case, a unix-time representation) of that object.

Class-level methods remain that, they don't get added to object instances. So when you create a `Date` instance, yes, all the *object* methods are inherited. The class-level methods are not.

Comment: So Date.now() is a constructor?

Comment: Technically, no. Internally, think of it as calling a constructor to create a Date object, which it then returns to you.

Comment: As per user1477388, Date.now() actually only returns an integer. But as per the docs, it creates a new Date object and uses getTime to return.

Comment: That's what I get for answering off the top of my head.