# What is the difference between getTime() vs Date.now()

Tags: javascript

I did not realize the difference between getTime() vs Date.now() in Javascript, both gives the same output ? Is there any difference ?

Comment: `Date.now` gives you the milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC to the current time, `.getTime` gives you milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC to the date the Date instance has been built on.

Comment: This question is duplicate of this Question/Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322583/date-gettime-v-s-date-now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there should be not difference between the OUTPUT of

`new Date().getTime()` (without a date string)

and `Date.now()`

> [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) The **static** Date.now() method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC. (Unix Epoch)

---

> [Date.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)
> The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch.
> JavaScript uses milliseconds as the unit of measurement, whereas Unix Time is in seconds.
> getTime() always uses UTC for time representation. For example, a client browser in one timezone, getTime() will be the same as a client browser in any other timezone.

```js
console.log(new Date().getTime(),Date.now())
```

If you add a string or (yyyy,mm-1,dd,hh,min,ss,ms) to the call the new Date() then you will get the number of milliseconds since Epoch to the date you specify:

```js
const d = new Date(2021,1,10,0,0,0,0)
console.log(d.getTime())
const diff = Math.abs(Date.now()-d.getTime()); // difference since 10th of Jan 2021
console.log(new Date(diff).toLocaleTimeString()); // diff WITH timezone offset
```

For a discussion vs object prototypes and static methods see [Date.getTime() v.s. Date.now()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322583/date-gettime-v-s-date-now)

Comment: There *would* be a difference if you construct a date object for a different time - `new Date('2020-08-05').getTime()`

Comment: Updated........